# jBPM with websphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jbpm

All,
I am new to jBPM.
I did a very basic example run using the link below

http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2010/02/01/updated-hello-world-tutorial-for-jbpm-4-3/

Though I got the example running, I have some questions on jBPM and integrating with my application on Websphere

1. I do not want to use the jbpm console for user interaction (like starting a process etc)
2. I need to understand what exact database setup jBPM needs (tables, entities) and I want to use the very minimal setup that needs to be used for jbpm
3. I want to use my own custom web-pages that will allow users of my application to interact with the workflows (starting, stopping) etc
4. do I need just the jbpm.jar library to run jbpm workflows or I need to take the entire library set (some 25 jars)

Can anybody point me to a proper tutorial that shows how to embed jbpm into an existing application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JBPM 4.4 blog, I recommend http://blog.aparnachaudhary.net/2010/08/19/jbpm4-4-with-spring3/ .

Even though there is no one whole book dedicated to JBPM 4, you can read `Spring Enterprise Reciepe` Chapter 11(Spring with JBPM) to see how to use Spring beans in JBPM4 . You can download the source code for the book from Apress website too. One thing to note is that the sample codes for books are using JBPM 4.0.

You can use the configurations from the above mentioned blog if you want to use JBPM 4.4.